# shift multidimentional array to single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I want to remove key 0 from parent array and set child array as parent.
Here I will get single value so one array is ok for me.

My current array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [api_key] => acount266
            [auth_domain] => Tester26
            [database_url] => vcc.test.acc+27@gmail.com
            [project_id] => 12345
            [storage_bucket] => 
            [secret_key_path] => 
            [fcm_server_key] => 1
            [messaging_sender_id] => 0
            [key_phrase] => 
            [disable] => 0
            [created] => 
            [updated] => 
        )

)
```

I want it like below. expected result

```
Array
(
            [id] => 3
            [api_key] => acount266
            [auth_domain] => Tester26
            [database_url] => vcc.test.acc+27@gmail.com
            [project_id] => 12345
            [storage_bucket] => 
            [secret_key_path] => 
            [fcm_server_key] => 1
            [messaging_sender_id] => 0
            [key_phrase] => 
            [disable] => 0
            [created] => 
            [updated] => 

)
```

For this I tried like below but no success.

```
$new = array();
foreach ($data as $v){
    $new = array_merge($new , array_values($v)) ;
}
```

but in my code it's removed key e.g id,api_key, etc....

I need key name also in my new array. please suggest

Comment: Have you tried `$array = $array[0];`?

Comment: @Lemon Kazi  One question : Whether your input array holds more elements ?

Comment: @MichaelThompson yeah I tried that's is one solution I know. but i want to unset parent array.

Comment: @Ajith not that will be one element only. it's coming from another resource. so I have to use it only the first element. and remove parent 0 index array

Comment: Does that not remove the existing data within the parent array? Such that [0] should cease to exist - you're replacing that way, not merging.
Otherwise, just `$new = $array[0]; unset($array);`?

Comment: If your array has more elements than just `$array[0]` then attempting to flatten it like this while retaining associative keys will cause all element values other than one to be lost because they will all have the same keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `array_values`

**Solution**

```
<?php 
    $test = array(
        array
            (
                'id' => 3,
                'api_key' => 'acount266'
            )
    );

    $new = array();
    foreach($test as $v){
        $new = array_merge($new, $v);
    }

    var_dump($new);
```

**Result**

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["api_key"]=>
  string(9) "acount266"
}
```

Comment: If the parent array contains more than 1 elements with the same keys, then each merge would overwrite an existing key value with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of PHP as mentioned

> reset() function returns the value of the first array element, or
>   FALSE if the array is empty.

```
$array = array(
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'api_key' => 'acount266',
            'auth_domain' => 'Tester26',
            'database_url' => 'vcc.test.acc+27@gmail.com',
            'project_id' => '12345',
            'storage_bucket' => '',
            'secret_key_path' => '',
            'fcm_server_key' => 1,
            'messaging_sender_id' => 0,
            'key_phrase' => '',
            'disable' => 0,
            'created' => '',
            'updated' => ''
        )
      );

      print_r(reset($test));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($examples as $example) {
    foreach ($example as $e) {
        array_push($arr, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer. but i think multiple loop is not good..

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate this, reassigning the first element to the parent array is quick and easy:

```
<?php

$array =
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'first' => 'Michael',
    'last' => 'Thompson'
  )
);

$array = $array[0];
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'first' => 'Michael',
    'last' => 'Thompson',
)
```

Or:

```
$array = array_shift($array);
```

Comment: (Did I fall into a trap?)